# Can i test a game in unity on ios publish it on android?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, testing, platform

I have a game that i want to test it on my iphone device but i want to publish it on android does it makes any difference between the two ?
That means the input and the movement and the screen size is all the same ?

Comment: If you aren't using any plugins you might be okay. It would be best to test on an Android device or emulator before publishing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can test your game on iOS and it should be fine on Android.

However, when switching the target platform to Android, there's a few things to remember:

- If you're using any iOS specific features, they won't be available on Android.
- Screen size might be different, but if you scale the UI that should be fine (considering iPhones have multiple screen sizes too).
- Input should be the same, especially if you're using Unity's InputManager.
- Unity is designed to switch and target multiple platforms with ease, as long as you don't use any third-party plugins that target specific platforms.
- Some phones might perform better than others, older iPhones or Android phones might run slower than newer ones.

I would recommend installing something like [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) or running an emulator in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator).

Answer (score 0):

There's also one thing, if you write your game in c# it should work well, but it might be a problem with javascript, but not necessarily. I've found some conversation about it, maybe it will help you: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-test-my-android-build-on-my-personal-device-before-publishing.630586/

Comment: I'm using c# but thanks for the advice cz I'm planning to learn javascript <3

Comment: Actually I don't recommend you learning JS if it is only for game dev, c# is much more powerful. But it is really good for web development, so if you want to do that type of things it is a great option. PS.  and it's really easy to learn.

Comment: Yeah I know I'm really hoping to get into web development in the next few months THX